# Unable to parse bindings in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Facing the common "Binding issue". Below is viewmodel

```
    function DetailListViewModel() {

    this.details = new Details();
    this.productdetails = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.show = function (item) {
        $.getJSON("Products.json", {}, function (data) {
            this.productdetails.push(this.details.init(data));
        });
    };
    }

    function Details() {
    this.author = ko.observable();
    this.text = ko.observable();
    this.init = function (temp) {
        return {
            author: temp.Author,
            text: temp.Text
        };
    };
    }

    var TaskListViewModel = {    
    tasks: ko.observableArray([]),
    addTask: function () {
    self.tasks.push(new Task({ BomID: this.BomID() }, { CreatedBy: this.CreatedBy() }));
    },
    ShowProductInfo: function (item) {       
        DetailListViewModel.show(item);
    }
    };


    $(function () {    
    $.getJSON("Tasks.json", function (allData)       {
            TaskListViewModel.tasks.push(toKoObserable($.parseJSON(allData.GetDataResult).RESULT.DOCUMENT));
        ko.applyBindings(TaskListViewModel);
        var DetailListViewModel = new DetailListViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(DetailListViewModel);
    });

    function toKoObserable(blog) {
        return {
            BomID: ko.observable(blog[0].BOMID),
            CreatedBy: ko.observable(blog[0].CreatedBy)
        };
    }
});
```

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: author is not defined;
Bindings value: text:author
```

my HTML is :

```
<h3  data-bind="text:author">/h3>
```

Comment: Try, this.author = ko.observable("");
this.text = ko.observable("");

Comment: applying bindings twice is not a good idea... what are you trying to do exactly? What is the html structure? Either provide a target element to apply the bindings to different parts of the page, or merge your view models into one and apply this to the page.

Comment: Hi Grim thanks for the comments but i am keeping seaparate view models for separate views, i want to refer other view models function. Initially i kept DetailListViewModel in separate js file it did not worked so i thought of moving in single file just to see whther binding works properly...

Comment: <div data-bind="template:{name: 'gridtemplate',foreach:tasks}" >
    </div>

    <div id="DetailsView" >
         <h3  data-bind="text:author"></h3>
          <p data-bind="text:text"></p>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that if you change your details implementation everything should work as you expect it. I am not sure why your details list contains a single details instance and then you create an observable array of details reusing that object. This does not seem right from a design point of view. Also your init does not return observable values. Try changing to something along these lines:

```
function Details(author, text) {
    this.author = ko.observable(author);
    this.text = ko.observable(text);
}
```

Then when you populate details list you would do:

```
function DetailListViewModel() {
    this.productdetails = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.show = function (item) {
        $.getJSON("Products.json", {}, function (data) {
            this.productdetails.push(new Details(data.Author, data.Text));
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin...Thanks...i have made the changes but still getting the same error. WHat i see during debugging in the Chrome console is that ko.applyBindings(DetailListViewModel); is never getting called...

Comment: modified the code now ko.applyBindings(DetailListViewModel) is getting called but still the same error...this issue is making me go mad...

Comment: You need to instantiate a new DataListViewModel and call apply bindings on that.

Comment: SO you mean to say it should be var TaskListViewModel = {    
    tasks: ko.observableArray([]),
    addTask: function () {
    self.tasks.push(new Task({ BomID: this.BomID() }, { CreatedBy: this.CreatedBy() }));
    },
    ShowProductInfo: function (item) { var DetailListViewModel=new DetailListViewModel();       
        DetailListViewModel.show(item);ko.applyBindings(DetailListViewModel);
    }
    };